# dijit.tree with empty folders

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, treeview, dojo

i have created a tree select that shows a dijit.tree in the dropdown. Now I do not want the user to select a folder even if it is empty. User should only be able to select the end nodes or leaves. dijit.tree treats all empty folders as leafs. how do I get that sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the _onClick or setSelected methods. This gets complicated if you use the multi-parental model ForestStoreModel.

See [fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/zawSX/2/)

Try doing as such, this will only work for select multiple false:

```
    getIconClass: function fileIconClass(item, nodeExpanded) {
        var store = item._S,
            get = function() {
                return store.getValue(item, arguments[0]);
            };
        // scope: dijit.Tree
        if (item.root || get("isDir")) {

            if (!item || this.model.mayHaveChildren(item) || get("isDir")) {
                return (nodeExpanded ? "dijitFolderOpened" : "dijitFolderClosed");
            } else {
                return "dijitLeaf";
            }

        } else {

            return "dijitLeaf";

        }
    },
    onClick: function(item, treeNode, e) {

        var store = item._S,
            get = function() {
                return store.getValue(item, arguments[0]);
            };
        if (get("isDir")) this.set("selectedItems", []);
    }
```

Adapt as you see fit, matching your json data - in particular the *isDir*, the above works on a sample of json like this

```
{
    identifier: 'id',
    label: 'foo',
    items: [
        {
        id: 'item1',
        foo: 'file1',
        isDir: false},
    {
        id: 'item2',
        foo: 'emptyDir',
        isDir: true},
    {
        id: 'item3',
        foo: 'dir',
        isDir: true,
        children: [
            {
            id: 'item3_1',
            foo: 'fileInDir',
            isDir: false}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: another thing which is bugging me is that some of my folders can be empty. so I don't want them to be selected either. I think my store will need to be customized some ting like that. do you have any tricks for that?

Comment: just out the box; i think you may need to set a value on a folder like `{ path:'/var/lib/modules/',isDir:true,isEmpty:true }` in which case you could check directly for 'if( ! (isDir) ) this.set("selectedItems...");' to avoid selecting folders - and if your folder is empty it will also get a leaf-icon (from stylesheet). Then in the the tree You can override the getIconClass function and return a class matching either folder or leaf (added a sample from my own dijit.Tree extension)

Comment: setselecteditems is not the right place. I dont want there to be any selection on the folder

Comment: the code becomes glitchy the moment I override that. can you please show a working example? probably at http://JSFiddle.net

Comment: very well, the contained answer should be simpler but with a slight overhead

Comment: Hi I have tried that and realized one more use case wrt this one, I want the + and - signs to be present for emplty folders

Comment: well good luck then :) is kinda off topic though and probably not what you would expect from a file browser. a leaf pr definition is something without children and you will not get expando-node on leaf is you dont hack pretty hardcore. make a stylesheet for file-types instead and pass the file extension/mime-type in your store so that getIconClass can set appropiately on media/text/spreadsheet/documents etc.

Comment: the thing is that I am not working on a file browser my friend. I am working on a tree select that has this requirement